# WPF UserControls: Image disappears even with 'x:Shared="False"'

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, user-controls, resources

I defined a style in a `ResourceDictionary` for a button with an image:

```
<Style x:Key="BotonIrAInicioStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Margin="2" Source="{StaticResource IconoDashboardBlanco}" MaxHeight="20" Stretch="Uniform"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The image source is defined in another `ResourceDictionary` in the same assembly, and marked as `x:Shared="False"`:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="IconoDashboardBlanco" x:Shared="False"
UriSource="pack://application:,,,/QualityFramework;component/Images/dashboard64X64.png"/>
```

Since the style will be used in a different assembly, I used the `"pack://application:,,,"` notation to reference the image. The `Build Action` for the image is set to `Resource (Do not copy to output directory)`.

In the main assembly I have two `UserControls` which display a button with identical style:

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource BotonIrAInicioStyle}" Click="BotonIrAInicio_Click"/> (Click event has nothing to do with the problem)
```

**PROBLEM:**

I open `UserControl A` containing the button with the image and the image is displayed ok. Then I open `UserControl B` containing an identical button, image ok. I open `UserControl A` again, and the image is gone. Happens the same if I open `UserControl B` and then `UserControl A`, the last one "owns" the image.

I went everywhere and all the solutions point to the `x:Shared="False"`, the `URI notation` and the `Build Action`... I applied all of them and the problem still happens. I also tried cleaning and rebuilding with no success.

What am I missing? Thanks!

PS: if I set the content of both buttons to the image directly it works ok, but the whole point of styling is to avoid exactly that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not the `BitmapImage` it's the content in the setter of the button - it's created once and thus has to "jump" between instances.

The easy, but not WPF-isque, solution is setting `x:Shared="False"` on the style.

The correct way is to use `ControlTemplate` or `DataTemplate`.

From your observations:

"*if I set the content of both buttons to the image directly it works ok*" - this is because to do that you create two different instances of `Image` object.

But, this: "*the whole point of styling is to avoid exactly that!*" is a misconception - styles are not meant to set the content of content controls, the content is dependent upon the context. If you have a visual that is repeating for all buttons (without dependency upon the content), it should reside in `ControlTemplate` for the button. If you have a visual that is dependent upon the content (but the content is not the visual) it should reside in `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution, you are absolutely right in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similary problem, it is not exatly the same thing but just in case i give you my solution it may help some other people o:)
I resolve it this way (in visual studio 2019, wpf application) :

put your images in your project in a folder
Create an image in xaml and put your source At this point for me the images are displayed in the design window but not at the runetime
Access to your image in your project with the solution explorer
Select each image and open the property window
Set "Generation action" to "Resource" and "Copy in the repository" To "always copy"

I have done that and i can see my images at runtime :)

PS : sorry for my english, i'm french